# Java Set, contains, false result

Tags: java, set, equals, contains, compareto

```
EventObject target = new EventObject("e2");
Set<EventObject> Following = o.getFollowingEvents(e1);
System.out.println("Elements : "+Following.toString());
System.out.println(e2.toString());
System.out.println(Following.toString()+" contains "+e2+" ? = "+Following.contains(target));
```

Print :

```
Elements : [e2, e5, end, T]
e2
[e2, e5, end, T] contains e2 ? = false
```

Equals and CompareTo :

```
@Override
public int compareTo(EventObject o) {
    return this.getName().compareTo(o.getName());
}

@Override 
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (obj instanceof EventObject) && (this.compareTo((EventObject) obj) == 0);
}
```

How is this possible, if the event is present on the Set ?

Comment: Have you overridden `hashCode`? You must do that, if your set is hash-based...

Comment: Hash sets compare hashcodes first.

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you've just forgotten to implement [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getName().hashCode(); // Consistent with equals
}
```

Note that you don't really need to perform an ordering comparison in your [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method - you just need to check whether or not the names are equal.